# How to trace which functions javascript event(click) goes through before it crashes?

Tags: javascript, debugging

So I am trying to debug my app and I am trying to determine what is causing my error  but I cannot simply look at Chrome's console because it only shows me which function last called it. I am trying to trace the whole path from an event to crash. Is there a way to do such a thing? Thanks!

Comment: Can't you turn on "Pause on all Exceptions" in your developer tools _Sources_ tab? Then the script should pause on your error and you can look at the call stack on the right hand side (of the Sources tab still).

Comment: The solution which @Barmar proposed worked perfectly. However, your solution sounds very promising as well! I will definitely give it a try next time!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a breakpoint at the beginning of the event handler function. When the event occurs, the program will stop in the debugger. Then you can use the single-step buttons to step through the code.

See [How to step through code in Google chrome javascript debugger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1576467/how-to-step-through-code-in-google-chrome-javascript-debugger?rq=1)